# Vector space example

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

What is an example of a vector space that is a non-linear map from the real vector space of all real-valued continuous functions on R to itself?

Comment: E.g. $x\mapsto x^2$ or $|x|$ or $\sin(x)$, $\dots$ these are not linear but continuous functions $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, so are elements of the given space.

Comment: How can any vector space (or any space consisting of multiple elements) be a "map"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you are looking for, but it fulfils your requirement:

Be $(\mathcal C,+,\cdot)$ the real vector space of all real-valued continuous functions on $\mathbb R$. Be $h\in\mathcal C$ a nonlinear function (for example $x\mapsto x^2$). Then this function induces a map $\phi_h$ from $\mathcal C$ to itself, by $\phi_h(f) = h\circ f$, and it is easily checked that $\phi_h$ is non-linear.

Now we only need to extend that function into a vector space. For this, we notice that a function is just a relation, that is, a set of pairs; in particular,
$$\phi_h = \{(f, \phi_h(f)): f\in \mathcal C\} \subset \mathcal C\times\mathcal C.$$
We now need to define an addition and a multiplication with scalar. For this we take advantage of the fact that $\mathcal C$ is already a real vector space, and from the fact that each pair is already determined by the first element (because $\phi_h$ is a function). Therefore we can define
$$\begin{align}
\oplus&: \mathcal C\times\mathcal C\to\mathcal C, &
(f, \phi_h(f)) \oplus (g, \phi_h(g)) &= (f+g, \phi_h(f+g))\\
\odot&: \mathbb R\times\mathcal C\to\mathcal C, &
\alpha\odot(f,\phi_h(f)) &= (\alpha f,\phi_h(\alpha f))
\end{align}$$
It is then not hard to check that $(\phi_h,\oplus,\odot)$ is indeed a real vector space.

Therefore $\phi_h$ is both a real vector space and a non-linear map from $\mathcal C$ to itself.